# Spring-webflux, how to get the request as parameter in @ExceptionHandler

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, spring-webflux

With spring webflux and the `@RestController` model, I have a `@RestControllerAdvice` with some `@ExceptionHandler` methods.

I would like to get the original request as parameter because I want to log it and use it in my response.

However I have tried all the possible types for an handler method in the classic MVC model but none of them was accepted (`HttpServletRequest`, `WebRequest` and `ServerRequest`).

What type can I use to access the original request in a webflux annotated handler method ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should use `org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest`, because:

- `HttpServletRequest` and `WebRequest` are Servlet/Spring MVC specific
- `ServerRequest` belongs to Spring WebFlux, but the functional variant

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was not expecting any result from `HttpServletRequest` and `WebRequest` but thinking that `ServerRequest` is used in both the functional and annotated controller model.